# get the size of an image to be uploaded in django before the upload process starts

Tags: python, django

Okay, I don't have a code snippet here, I wanted to display a progress bar when I am uploading an image in Django, am using celery and some other stuff, `but most importantly i will need to know the size of the file been uploaded so that I can compute the progress of the upload, any suggestion or solutions, please.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def file_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['filename']:
        file = request.FILES['file']
        print(file.size)
        # do whatever you want here
    return render(request, 'file_upload.html')
```